# eslint "synckit" resolve error where yarn berry pnp

Tags: typescript, eslint, yarnpkg

when run `next lint` or `eslint` below error has occured

```bash
./src/pages/_app.page.tsx
1:1  Error: Resolve error: synckit tried to access ", but it isn't declared in its dependencies; this makes the require call ambiguous and unsound.

Required package: " (via ""/var/folders/r5/t0tjw7_91jd13k8q394g4rcm0000gn/T/9445377a1432a3a6969b16dffa53635b.cjs"")
Required by: synckit@npm:0.8.5 (via /Users/hyesungoh/Documents/depromeet13/13th-3team-client/.yarn/cache/synckit-npm-0.8.5-40a594eb38-8a9560e5d8.zip/node_modules/synckit/lib/)

Require stack:
- /Users/hyesungoh/Documents/depromeet13/13th-3team-client/.yarn/cache/synckit-npm-0.8.5-40a594eb38-8a9560e5d8.zip/node_modules/synckit/lib/index.cjs
- /Users/hyesungoh/Documents/depromeet13/13th-3team-client/.yarn/__virtual__/eslint-import-resolver-typescript-virtual-60d6e9517b/0/cache/eslint-import-resolver-typescript-npm-3.5.5-ea69fbfbc9-27e6276fdf.zip/node_modules/eslint-import-resolver-typescript/lib/index.cjs
- /Users/hyesungoh/Documents/depromeet13/13th-3team-client/.yarn/__virtual__/eslint-module-utils-virtual-06b9a420ed/0/cache/eslint-module-utils-npm-2.7.4-a1640084cb-5da13645da.zip/node_modules/eslint-module-utils/resolve.js
- /Users/hyesungoh/Documents/depromeet13/13th-3team-client/.yarn/__virtual__/eslint-plugin-import-virtual-8fa3bc1c04/0/cache/eslint-plugin-import-npm-2.27.5-35b044b26f-f500571a38.zip/node_modules/eslint-plugin-import/lib/rules/no-unresolved.js
- /Users/hyesungoh/Documents/depromeet13/13th-3team-client/.yarn/__virtual__/eslint-plugin-import-virtual-8fa3bc1c04/0/cache/eslint-plugin-import-npm-2.27.5-35b044b26f-f500571a38.zip/node_modules/eslint-plugin-import/lib/index.js
- /Users/hyesungoh/Documents/depromeet13/13th-3team-client/.yarn/cache/@eslint-eslintrc-npm-2.0.2-d308674d86-cfcf5e12c7.zip/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/dist/eslintrc.cjs
    at Function.require$$0.Module._resolveFilename (/private/var/folders/r5/t0tjw7_91jd13k8q394g4rcm0000gn/T/9445377a1432a3a6969b16dffa53635b.cjs:18644:13)
    at Function.mod._resolveFilename (/Users/hyesungoh/Documents/depromeet13/13th-3team-client/.yarn/__virtual__/next-virtual-927f404d20/0/cache/next-npm-13.3.0-40476f73c1-24e0e013e8.zip/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/require-hook.js:23:32)
    at Function.mod._resolveFilename (/Users/hyesungoh/Documents/depromeet13/13th-3team-client/.yarn/__virtual__/eslint-config-next-virtual-734c04f0e8/0/cache/eslint-config-next-npm-13.3.0-3b8aee6f6c-19894044c4.zip/node_modules/eslint-config-next/index.js:49:26)
    at Function.mod._resolveFilename (/Users/hyesungoh/Documents/depromeet13/13th-3team-client/.yarn/__virtual__/eslint-config-next-virtual-734c04f0e8/0/cache/eslint-config-next-npm-13.3.0-3b8aee6f6c-19894044c4.zip/node_modules/eslint-config-next/index.js:49:26)
    at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:19)
    at /Users/hyesungoh/Documents/depromeet13/13th-3team-client/.yarn/cache/synckit-npm-0.8.5-40a594eb38-8a9560e5d8.zip/node_modules/synckit/lib/index.cjs:174:92
    at Array.some (<anonymous>)
    at setupTsRunner (/Users/hyesungoh/Documents/depromeet13/13th-3team-client/.yarn/cache/synckit-npm-0.8.5-40a594eb38-8a9560e5d8.zip/node_modules/synckit/lib/index.cjs:173:68)
    at startWorkerThread (/Users/hyesungoh/Documents/depromeet13/13th-3team-client/.yarn/cache/synckit-npm-0.8.5-40a594eb38-8a9560e5d8.zip/node_modules/synckit/lib/index.cjs:205:7)
    at Object.createSyncFn (/Users/hyesungoh/Documents/depromeet13/13th-3team-client/.yarn/cache/synckit-npm-0.8.5-40a594eb38-8a9560e5d8.zip/node_modules/synckit/lib/index.cjs:76:18)  import/no-duplicates
```

Im using yarn berry with pnp ...

and Im using below eslint plugins

```
 plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'simple-import-sort', 'unused-imports', 'testing-library', 'unicorn'],
  extends: [
    'next/core-web-vitals',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
```

how can I solve this error?

---

CI environment run well

https://github.com/depromeet/13th-3team-client/actions/runs/4758988048/jobs/8457735417?pr=12

I do not know why this error occured at local

Comment: Please clarify something for us readers: does the output literally say `Error: Resolve error: synckit tried to access ", but it isn't declared`? Because it *looks* like a copy-paste error where you have omitted the actual package name. If that is the exact error message then please post any `import`/`require` statements at the top of `_app.page.tsx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try adding this code to your `eslint.js`.

```
settings: {
    'import/resolver': 'node',
  },
```

Comment: Thanks! It works well!

but I do not know why this worked 

Comment: I thought module resolution was a problem, so I answered as above.
This link may help you understand.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html